# Count number of rows and number of value matches

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(m.winner = p.userName) AS wins, YEAR(m.datePlayed) AS year, DATE_FORMAT(m.datePlayed, '%M') AS month, COUNT(*) as games FROM allMatches AS m LEFT JOIN playerUsers AS p ON m.season = p.season AND (m.player1 = p.userName OR m.player2 = p.userName) WHERE p.realName = '$realName' AND m.winner != '' AND m.canceled != '1' GROUP BY YEAR(m.datePlayed), MONTH(m.datePlayed)";
```

We have 2 tables we're joining: allMatches and playerUsers. A PlayerUser has a username which matches to either player1 or player2 (and possibly to winner) on the allMatches table for a given season.

I want to count the number of games played (any match they're in) and the number of games they've won (where their username on playerUsers matches winner on allMatches). The above SQL statement returns both wins and games as the same number. Is there a way to count the number of wins and games in the same SQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` to calculate the number of wins:

```
SELECT SUM(m.winner = p.userName) AS wins, ...
```

It works because the boolean expression evaluates to either 0 and 1, and so `SUM` gives you the total number of rows where the expression was true.